# Optimize PostgreSQL query timeseries with intervals

Tags: postgresql, time-series

I have a table with events with `first_seen` (datetime), `last_seen` (datetime) and `severity` (an integer).

I'm trying to find how many events were active in discreet 15 minute intervals:

```
WITH intervals AS
  (
      SELECT
        '2016-08-02 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
            + (n||' minutes')::INTERVAL AS start_time,
        '2016-08-02 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
            + ((n + 15)||' minutes')::INTERVAL AS end_time
      FROM generate_series(0, 24 * 60, 15) n
  )
SELECT
  start_time,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM event
     WHERE first_seen < end_time AND last_seen > start_time
       AND severity = 5) red,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM event
     WHERE first_seen < end_time AND last_seen > start_time
       AND severity = 4) orange,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM event
     WHERE first_seen < end_time AND last_seen > start_time
       AND severity = 3) yellow
FROM intervals;
```

I also have an index on `(first_seen, last_seen, severity)`.
My problem is that it seems to be a be too slow.
The table has about 100 thousand rows, and to make 100 intervals takes 10 seconds. The index scan seems too slow.

Any ideas how to optimize this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing is to get rid of the subselects.

Try something like the following (untested, so it may contain errors):

```
WITH intervals AS
  (
      SELECT
        '2016-08-02 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
            + (n||' minutes')::INTERVAL AS start_time,
        '2016-08-02 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
            + ((n + 15)||' minutes')::INTERVAL AS end_time
      FROM generate_series(0, 24 * 60, 15) n
  )
SELECT
   start_time,
   sum(CASE WHEN severity = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) red,
   sum(CASE WHEN severity = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) orange,
   sum(CASE WHEN severity = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) yellow
FROM event
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN intervals
      ON first_seen < end_time AND last_seen > start_time
GROUP BY start_time;
ORDER BY start_time;
```

You may be able to speed up things by two indexes on `first_seen` and `last_seen`. A multicolumn index will not help.

Comment: Note: generate_series() works with timestamps, too: `WITH intervals AS (
      SELECT gs AS start_time
        , gs + '15 minutes' AS end_time
        FROM generate_series('2016-08-02 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
                        ,'2016-08-03 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
                        , '15 minutes'::INTERVAL) gs
        )
`

Comment: Yes. I left that part the same to reduce potential confusion.

Comment: Wow, that's 2 times faster. Thanks :D.

Comment: I have added hints for potential indexes.

Comment: I also needed the intervals that have sum 0 so I added a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of join. Also an `ORDER BY start_time` at the end.

Comment: Edited the answer to contain your fixes. Yes, it will use the index, but only the first column, so you are cheaper if you create the index only with this one column. If you have two indexes as I suggested, it *may* use a bitmap index scan and combine the information. Depends on the data if the planner chooses to do that or not.

Comment: It also seems to use the multi column index (it also has simple on first_seen and last_seen) `...->  Index Only Scan using alert_dashboard_alertdashboar_first_seen_last_seen_severity_idx on alert_dashboard_alertdashboardevent  (cost=0.42..649.96 rows=16166 width=18)`

Comment: Yes it uses the index, but what is the `Index Cond`?

Comment: Ah, you're right `Index Cond: ((first_seen < intervals.end_time) AND (last_seen > intervals.start_time))`, I could have only those two single column indexes.